# My HTML website extension file is not working

Tags: html

So I just started learning HTML and I wanted to start my first basic project. I am creating a website that allows the user to learn about the different coding languages. The home page is basic as of now, but it includes a link to learn more about HTML. However, that link does not work. I used `<a href>` and have it saved as a local file in the same folder as the home page, but on Chrome, it says, "Your file couldn’t be accessed". I included screenshots of the message, files, and the code itself.

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYFlT.png)

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9q13.png)
[Home Page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPfhX.png)

[HTML webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRBWJ.png)
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1otL.png)

I am wanting the HTML link to bring me to my second file of code that explains what HTML is.

codes for link to HTML page:

```
<a href="/html.html>HTML</a>
```

Code for gong back to coding page:

```
<a href="/coding.html>BACK</a>
```

Comment: Did you place your files directly in c: drive?

Comment: you should paste the actual code into your question rather than pasting an image of the code

Comment: drag your html file into your browser and see what the url displays

Comment: Paths starting with / are root-relative, which doesn't really work when you're opening your HTML from the filesystem (it takes you to C: drive). If you're using VS Code, you can download Live Server extension to simulate working with a real server.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is that your setting your href path to "/code.html", this will send you to the root of wherever you're loading your file (In this case, the root of your C: disk).

What you want in this case is to use relative paths, which take as a starting point, the root of your project (HTML Project 1).

You can use as some other comments says just "code.html" and it will infeer the relative path but it would be better to use "./" as it is what indicates the path is actually relative at the begining, specially if you'll work in the future with more folders for your routing.

so for your code, you'll have "./code.html"

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove `/` in `href`
if both html files are in the same folder

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the `/` before the file name.

```
<a href="coding.html">
```

Comment: Please elaborate on why this is working (relative URL instead of starting from root) for a complete answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

using only `/` is pointing to the absolute root directory where in your case it is `C:` drive in your computer regardless of the directory you used (desktop or any other directory in C drive).

You need to use `./` to point to the base url where by default it is the current directory if you have not defined base url in the header.

Or you may omit / and set only `html.html` or `coding.html` as href value if you **didn't set base url** in your document **and** all files are in a same directory

Comment: The expert guy who has something in their head and is giving negative points to all answers, it is better to tell something instead.